# Why is the file saved showing None while console shows the correct response?

Tags: python, text, python-requests, output, concurrent.futures

When I try to save the responses to a file, the actual response is not saved even though it shows in the console. The result that is saved in the file is None. See examples below

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
#from timer import timer


#########  create test file

URLsTest = '''
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFL
'''.strip()

with open('input.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(URLsTest)
    
####################

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls=f.read().split('\n')    # url list

def fetch(tt):  # received tuple
    session, url = tt
    print('Processing')
    with session.get(url) as response:
        print(response.text)

#@timer(1, 5)
def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:  # for now, just one session
            results = executor.map(fetch, [(session, u) for u in urls])  # tuple list (session, url), each tuple passed to function
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
    # write all results to text file
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
        for r in results:  # tuple (url, html)
            f2.write("%s\n" % r)
            
main()
```

Response file - output.txt

```
None    
None
```

Comment: What is `fetch` returning?

Comment: Just to say though, for opening input.txt you don't have to use `urls=f.read().split('\n')` you can use `f.readlines()` and it returns a list of lines

Comment: `executor.map` is (semi) lazy, and the results it computes may be tied to the lifetime of the executor. Try putting the `with open` block inside the scope of the `with ThreadPoolExecutor` block (and don't shut it down at all; the `with` block is handling that for you anyway).

Comment: @Carcigenicate It is returning the response of the url, in this case the whole contents of the each page that is called

Comment: @ShadowRanger can you please provide an example? I'm not understanding

Comment: @mjebay7 `fetch` isn't returning anything though; it's printing. If you don't return anything from a function, `None` is automatically returned... and that `None` is ending up in `results`. You need to explicitly `return` to return a value from a function.

Comment: @Hedy so just urls=f.readlines() will work here?

Comment: Yes if what you are trying to get is a list of lines

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see. That's why the console is showing that response being printed. How can I modify this so that the results are printed into a file?

Comment: `return response.text` after the existing `print` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could avoid printing the html since you are saving that output to a file. That way you can avoid using resources to print the results.

Then, your fetch is not returning anything for the `results`. Therefore you should change your `print` for a `return`
So instead of printing return the `response.text`

```
# print(response.text)
return response.text
```

Answer (score -2):

The ideal practice is not to print the html, it is so as you have to save the work or output to a file which disables you from printing the entire results in their original shape.

Comment: This sounds sorta like you might know the problem, but it's failing to actually make clear what they need to do to fix it, and it's too ambiguous describing the problem for them to figure it out.